# syntax error in postman after json_encode()

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**this is my contoller**

```
$pid = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
            foreach ($pid as $key => $value) {
                foreach ($value as $keys => $values) {
                    $c_res = $this->Model_master->get_sup($values);
                    echo json_encode($c_res, 200);
                } 
             }
```

**this is my model**

```
                $q = $this->db->select('contact_number')->from('shopxie_people')
                                ->where("p_id = ".$value)
                                ->get();
                return $q->result_array();
```

this shows me result in html form but when i change it to json it gives me

> SYntax error

also in postman content-type is showing as text/html;

why does it happen even after encoding in json in my code?

Comment: What do you mean by "change it to json"? Can you share the exact error message?

Comment: what is `200` in `json_encode($c_res, 200)` just remove it

Comment: @pradeep still it gives the same error

Comment: keep it out of foreach loop

Comment: @NicoHaase i am using postman so i get option of changing my output to html, json, xml, text, auto

Comment: show ur full code

Comment: @pradeep then i will only get the result of first element in my input array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Do something like this in your controller :

```
foreach ($pid as $key => $value) 
{
   foreach ($value as $keys => $values) 
   {
      $c_res[] = $this->Model_master->get_sup($values);  
   }
}
echo json_encode($c_res);
exit;
```

Comment: pleasure is mine, happy coding